# error installing older mono version despite following tutorial

Tags: ubuntu, mono, monodevelop, apt

I need to install an older version of mono and followed the official tutorial where I added in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list` the following

```
deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable/snapshots/4.8.1 main
```

Updating the repository works out well. But when I try to install it via

```
sudo apt install mono-complete

or

sudo apt install mono-devel
```

I am not getting version 4.8.1 as specified but the newest version 6.8.

What am I doing wrong here and how do I force install the older version?

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/ With the changes in the past few years, you should assume something like that can be gone for ever. Ask yourself why you ever need that old Mono version in the end, and find alternatives.

Comment: I need that mono version. There is no alternatives for me and this particular project.

Comment: Then the alternative is to complete replace that particular project. While it is still possible to compile Mono 4.8.1 from source code, you shouldn't expect many people remember the details.